# Замена текста и печать в C#

Tags: c#

У меня вопрос. Как мне с помощью C# создать к примеру текстовый документ по определенному шаблону, и отправить его на печать, заменяя переменные в тексте.
К примеру:

```
            Поставка груза:
Название: textbox1.Text .
Ответственный: Combobox1.Text .
```

Чтобы в итоге было:

```
            Поставка груза:
Название: Андромеда.
Ответственный: Андрей Васильевич Прага.
```

Comment: Ну для изменения можете использовать `"Текст " + textbox1.Text + "Текст"` итд... Либо `$"Текст {textBox1.text} текст"`, либо и вовсе `string.Format("Текст {0} текс", textBox1.text)`. А вот что касается печати, то смотрите в сторону [PrintDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-print-a-multi-page-text-file-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Если без форматирования - TXT. Если с форматированием - попробуйте RTF (Rich text format). Возможно прийдется дописать перевод текста в escape-формат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмем для примера самый элементарный вариант.

Создадим проект Windows Forms с такой формой

[image: Изображение формы]

Добавим на форму PrintDocument и PrintPreviewDialog и свяжем их так
[image: свойства PrintPreviewDialog]

Код будет таким

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Поставка груза",
                                new Font("Times New Romans", 16, FontStyle.Bold),
                                Brushes.Black,
                                new PointF(220, 100));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(label1.Text,
                                new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Regular),
                                Brushes.Black,
                                new PointF(100, 150));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(textBoxName.Text + ".",
                                new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Regular),
                                Brushes.Black,
                                new PointF(260, 150));

        e.Graphics.DrawString(label2.Text,
                                new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Regular),
                                Brushes.Black,
                                new PointF(100, 185));
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboBoxFirm.Text + ".",
                                new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Regular),
                                Brushes.Black,
                                new PointF(260, 185));

    }

    private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //размер бумаги
            PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
            printDocument1.PrinterSettings = settings;
            var a4 = settings.PaperSizes
                                        .Cast<PaperSize>()
                                        .First(size => size.Kind == PaperKind.A4);
            printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = a4;

            printDocument1.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Получается так

[image: пример работы]