# Печать данных из listView

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно данные которые я добавляю  в ListView Распечатать . Как это сделать вот мой код , где я добавляю и удаляю эти данные

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFIO.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Txtname.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
            return;

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(txtFIO.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(Txtname.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(textBox2.Text);
        listView.Items.Add(item);
        txtFIO.Clear();
        Txtname.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox1.Clear();
        txtFIO.Focus();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView.Items.Count > 0)
            listView.Items.Remove(listView.SelectedItems[0]);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

}

Comment: На принтере?Есла да, то это дубликат, погугли

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/824392/222542

Comment: я вместо label вожжу listview , но ничего не печатается

Answer (score 0):

Для такой формы
[image: пример формы]

Такой код

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //список людей для печати
    private List<string> _peopleForPrint;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Text = "Пример";
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        SetupListView();

        _buttonAdd.Click += ButtonAdd_Click;
        _buttonPrint.Click += ButtonPrint_Click;
        _printDocument.PrintPage += PrintDocument_PrintPage;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Настройка ListView
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupListView()
    {
        _listView.View = View.Details;
        _listView.FullRowSelect = true;
        _listView.GridLines = true;

        // Столбцы
        _listView.Columns.Add("Фамилия", 200, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        _listView.Columns.Add("Имя", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
        _listView.Columns.Add("Отчество", 250, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Добавить
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textBoxFirstName.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textBoxLastName.Text)
            || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_textBoxMiddleName.Text))
            return;

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(_textBoxLastName.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(_textBoxFirstName.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add(_textBoxMiddleName.Text);
        _listView.Items.Add(item);

        _textBoxFirstName.Clear();
        _textBoxLastName.Clear();
        _textBoxMiddleName.Clear();
        _textBoxLastName.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Кнопка Печать
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void ButtonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //список для печати
        _peopleForPrint = GetPeople();

        if (_printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //размер бумаги
            PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
            _printDocument.PrinterSettings = settings;
            var a4 = settings.PaperSizes
                                        .Cast<PaperSize>()
                                        .First(size => size.Kind == PaperKind.A4);
            _printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = a4;
            //печатаем
            _printDocument.Print();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Извлечение списка людей из ListView
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private List<string> GetPeople()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in _listView.Items)
        {
            var lastName = item.SubItems[0].Text;
            var firstName = item.SubItems[1].Text;
            var middleName = item.SubItems[2].Text;
            result.Add($"{lastName} {firstName} {middleName}");
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Печать страницы документа
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void PrintDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Список сотрудников",
                            new Font("Times New Romans", 16, FontStyle.Bold),
                            Brushes.Black,
                            new PointF(220, 100));

        if (_peopleForPrint == null || _peopleForPrint.Count == 0)
            return;

        float y = 150;
        foreach (var person in _peopleForPrint)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(person,
                            new Font("Times New Romans", 14, FontStyle.Regular),
                            Brushes.Black,
                            new PointF(100, y += 30));
        }
    }
}
```

Получается так
[image: пример печати]

Пример [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples2/tree/master/WinFormsListViewPrint).